# Patching sshuttle's firewall.py -- IPFW to PF

Tags: python

Has anyone fixed 'firewall.py' for sshuttle to use PF instead of IPFW for the Yosemite 10.10 update?

https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle
https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle/blob/master/firewall.py

I have looked around for a fix, but nothing seems to be available yet. I am more of rails guy, and don't  know python too well. Besides being able to make a little sense of it, I don't know where to begin with making this change and hoping the community could help, or hoping someone has a fork already fixed.

Comment: For anyone dealing with this, I found the best solution is doing a standard ssh tunnel. You can do this by ssh -D 5000 -N user@server and setting your browser's proxy setting to use SOCKS at 127.0.0.1 port 5000 -- This will of course tunnel all web traffic, so be sure to change whatever protocol you're using.

Comment: SSH tunnel will not give you the flexibility of sshuttles. Even if you confiure system level proxy to use ssh tunnel, some apps still won't use that configuration. So I would prefer sshhutle. I hope a fix for Yosemite will come soon.

Comment: @larwa1N Yea I agree. Also you might need to speed it up. If you're using it and it's slow, you can use this link to help: http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/mac/fix_ssh_connection_delays

Comment: Unrelated to sshuttle, but I actually went with setting my vps as a vpn instead, and it is a lot faster than ssh tunneling and sshuttle. sshutle has been awesome and is really handy is some circumstances, but I think I'll stick with VPN for a while. And I like that that UDP and TCP are both being transferred.

Comment: I spent a while trying to get PacketFilter to work. There seems to be a feature missing. I wrote it up here: [Using PacketFilter to transparently proxy packets in OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873329/using-packetfilter-to-transparently-proxy-packets-in-os-x)

Answer (score 10):

**Update:** The pull request mentioned below, still fails after some time.

**Original answer**

[Philip Thrasher](https://github.com/pthrasher) har finalized [Fredrik Gustafsson's](https://github.com/jagheterfredrik) work and created a [pull request](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle/pull/3) for sshuttle.

I tried it out and was able to get it to work (at the least for outgoing connections). I used this script:

```
#/bin/bash
sudo echo "Installing PyXAPI"
curl -O http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~ylg/PyXAPI/PyXAPI-0.1.tar.gz
tar -xzvf PyXAPI-0.1.tar.gz
cd PyXAPI-0.1
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ..

echo "Installing autossh"
brew update
brew install autossh

echo "Getting sshuttle"
git clone https://github.com/pthrasher/sshuttle.git
cd sshuttle/src/
echo "Please add '`pwd`' to your path or run 'alias sshuttle=`pwd`/sshuttle'"
```

after this I can run it like usual

```
sshuttle -r user@server 0.0.0.0/0 -vv
```

Answer (score 8):

Taken from Tom Luff's comment in the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sshuttle/jdTzJGjTDMg):

> There are a few forks of the repository that have begun work on
>   supporting the new packet filter interface (pfctl). I've not actually
>   tried any of them yet but it could be worth looking over them.
>
> This seems to be the most recent:
>   https://github.com/zabracks/sshuttle/
>
> This also looks promising:
>   https://github.com/jagheterfredrik/sshuttle

Comment: Did you do anything special to get zabracks' fork to work? When I try it seems to launch fine, but doesn't do any proxying.

Comment: @Tobber I'm sorry, you're right. I thought it was working however I was looking at cached content. I've updated my answer to reflect.

Comment: https://github.com/jagheterfredrik/sshuttle.git works in Mac OS X 10.10